# Optimise jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, optimization

i have read that some selectors can be obtimised to use `querySelectorAll()`.
and this is an example.

```
$('a.button:animated'); // Does not use querySelectorAll()
$('a.button').filter(':animated');  // Uses it and faster.
```

and i have this selector :

```
 $( 'input[name="annoncedby"]:radio' ).on('change',function(){
   ....
 }
```

i used it like that :

```
  $( 'input[name="annoncedby"]').filter(':radio' ).on('change',function(){
   ....
   }
```

But its not fast , how can this be done to be faster thanks?

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? It didn't use `querySelectorAll`, or it didn't produce the desired results?

Comment: What happened instead?

Comment: sorry i mean its not fast . i edited. it works but not faster.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/queryselectorvssizzle

Comment: That's about as fast as you'll get it without resorting to using classnames or an id.

Comment: How can we optimize selectors for html we can't see?

Comment: A *delegated event handler* will provide faster *initial event registration*, with only an unnoticeable delay added to the event handling. Added more details below.

Comment: Have added a JSPerf to answer below. For obvious reasons, a delegated event handler is a lot faster (around 3 times faster than `$( 'input[name="annoncedby"]:radio' )`!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to use a delegated event handler, attached to an ancestor of all the radio buttons.

This will provide much faster *initial event hookup* and no noticeable decrease in speed *at event time*:

```
$('#someparentid').on('change', 'input[name="annoncedby"]:radio', function(){
   ....
});
```

It works by applying a *single event handler*, which listens for the `change` event to bubble up to the ancestor element, *then* applies the jQuery selector to the elements in the bubble-chain, *then* applies the function to *any matching elements that caused the event*. As the event response is only at user-interface speeds, there is no real down-side to using this approach.

To give you an idea of the speed difference of event registration, I have updated the JSPerf test from `@Musa`. The only addition to the HTML was a parent element to connect the handler to.

**JSPerf:** http://jsperf.com/queryselectorvssizzle/2

Comment: first point about what the event is isn't really relevant. Issue is about locating the elements to bind that event

Comment: @charlietfl: Point taken. Have removed the irrelevant part. The key is that a single delegated event handler will be much faster to wire up.

Comment: Thanks :) , i have seen the changing in time with your answer thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind those optimisations is that sizzle will not be needed if [standards-based query selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) are used, and if you need to use a [sizzle-only selector](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation), you add it in it's own clause, and JQuery is smart enough to make the optimisations.

This code circumvents JQuery altogether, ensuring maximum performance:

```js
"use strict";

//  various ways to select the element
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('[name="annoncedby"]');
//var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="annoncedby"]');
//var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="annoncedby"][type="radio"]');

for (var i in radios) {
  radios[i].addEventListener('change',function(event){
    alert( this.value );
  });  
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="annoncedby" value="daryl" />  
  <input type="radio" name="annoncedby" value="pete" />
</form>
```

Comment: so in your example its better to dont use `filter(':radio' )` ? and it will anyway select the radios ?

Comment: no, it's not better to use use `filter(':radio')`. It's better to use `[type="radio"]'` because querySelectorAll() can handle it